# Json import leads to ValueError: Mixing dicts with non-Series may lead to ambiguous ordering

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a *.json data set with country geometries/shapes called `world-110m.json` (see below). I suspect that it may origin from https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors/.

I try to import the file in Pandas via:

```
import pandas as pd
world_json = pd.read_json('world-110m.json')
```

But I receive the following error:

```
ValueError: Mixing dicts with non-Series may lead to ambiguous ordering.
```

Any idea how this can be solved? I need this specific file and I cannot download another version from NaturalEarthData.com.

```json
{
  "type": "Topology",
  "arcs""transform": {
    "scale": [
      0.012741070487533123,
      0.008502952811159802
    ],
    "translate": [
      -179.99999999999997,
      -55.60772818836408
    ]
  },
  "objects": {
    "collection": {
      "type": "GeometryCollection",
      "geometries": [
        {
          "arcs": [
            [
              0,
              1,
              2,
              3,
              4,
              5
            ]
          ],
          "type": "Polygon",
          "properties": {
            "name": "Afghanistan",
            "nameLong": "Afghanistan",
            "abbrev": "Afg.",
            "isoA2": "AF",
            "isoA3": "AFG",
            "continent": "Asia"
          }
        },
        {
```

Full file available via: https://pastebin.com/d6E2WYVw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am making an assumption on what information you need from the file, but no matter the information you want, the concept is the same.

```
import json
import pandas as pd

# your path the the json file
path = r'your\file\path'

# open your json file and read it using json.load
with open(path) as data:    
    d = json.load(data)  
    
# use json_normalize to create your dataframe
df = pd.json_normalize(d['objects']['collection']['geometries'])

                                       arcs          type  \
0                      [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]       Polygon   
1          [[[6, 7, 8, 9]], [[10, 11, 12]]]  MultiPolygon   
2                    [[13, 14, 15, 16, 17]]       Polygon   
3                    [[18, 19, 20, 21, 22]]       Polygon   
4  [[[23, 24]], [[25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30]]]  MultiPolygon   

        properties.name   properties.nameLong properties.abbrev  \
0           Afghanistan           Afghanistan              Afg.   
1                Angola                Angola              Ang.   
2               Albania               Albania              Alb.   
3  United Arab Emirates  United Arab Emirates            U.A.E.   
4             Argentina             Argentina              Arg.   

  properties.isoA2 properties.isoA3 properties.continent  
0               AF              AFG                 Asia  
1               AO              AGO               Africa  
2               AL              ALB               Europe  
3               AE              ARE                 Asia  
4               AR              ARG        South America
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! However, for me this yields `AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'json_normalize'`.

Comment: You are using and old version of pandas. You will need to import the module: `from pandas.io.json import json_normalize` then instead of doing `pd.json_normalize` you will just call `json_normalize`

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Strange, I updated pandas but it still does not work. But it seems like it may be a problem with Spyder IDE `This command failed to be executed because an error occurred while trying to get the file code from Spyder's editor. The error was:


An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

TypeError: handle_get_file_code() got an unexpected keyword argument 'save_all'`.

Comment: That seems like an odd traceback. I do not use Spyder so I do not know how much help I can provide.